# Removing Specified Punctuation From Strings

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a String that in need to convert into a `String[]` of each word in the string. However I do not need any white space or any punctuation EXCEPT hyphens and Apostrophes that belong in the word.

**Example Input:**

`Hello! This is a test and it's a short-er 1. - [ ] { } ___)`

**Example of the Array made from Input:**

`[ "Hello", "this", "is", "a", "test", "and", "it's", "a", "short-er", "1" ]`

Currently this is the code I have tried

(Note: the 2nd gives an error later in the program when `string.First()` is called):

```
private string[] ConvertWordsFromFile(String NewFileText)
{
     char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '/', '|', '<', '>', '/', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '"', '(', ')', ';' };
     string[] words = NewFileText.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
     return words;
}
```

or

```
private string[] ConvertWordsFromFile(String NewFileText)
{     
    return Regex.Split(NewFileText, @"\W+");
}
```

The second example crashes with the following code

```
private string GroupWordsByFirstLetter(List<String> words)
{
    var groups =
        from w in words
        group w by w.First();
    return FormatGroupsByAlphabet(groups);
}
```

specifically, when `w.First()` is called.

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: How to remove all punctuation other then hyphens and apostrophes that are in the middle of words (and belong there)

Comment: How should one decide if an apostrophe is 'legal' or not with regard to James' question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove unwanted characters from a String

```
string randomString = "thi$ is h@ving s*me inva!id ch@rs";
string excpList ="$@*!";
```

LINQ Option 1

```
var chRemoved = randomString
                  .Select(ch => excpList.Contains(ch) ? (char?)null : ch);

var Result = string.Concat(chRemoved.ToArray());
```

LINQ Option 2

```
var Result = randomString.Split().Select(x => x.Except(excList.ToArray()))
                                      .Select(c => new string(c.ToArray()))
                                      .ToArray();
```

Comment: But that does not return a string[]. How do I convert that to a String array? Also I'm not fluent in linq but i would prefer to use it

Comment: This code also causes and error similar to 2nd example. I will ad the conflicting code to the question.

Comment: When I run the program and try to load the words and call GroupByFristLetter() the line w.First() has an error. it's claiming that w contains no elements.

Comment: you should not be using first on a query.most of the times you may or may not have elements in your result

Comment: Then what would be an alternative? Because The program needs to group the words in the list by first letter.

Comment: Your edit only sorts the words I need them grouped. Also My method FormatGroupsByAlphabet takes (IEnumerable<IGrouping<char, string>>)

Comment: @james just cant belev i read group as sort.i hav 2 go to sleep.please check my edit

Comment: This is still not exactly right but I'm sure it's better code then what i had. Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little something I worked up. Splits on `\n` and removes any unwanted characters.

```
    private string ValidChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789'-";
    private IEnumerable<string> SplitRemoveInvalid(string input)
    {
        string tmp = "";
        foreach(char c in input)
        {
            if(c == '\n')
            {
                if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tmp))
                {
                    yield return tmp;
                    tmp = "";
                }
                continue;
            }
            if(ValidChars.Contains(c))
            {
                tmp += tmp;
            }
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tmp)) yield return tmp;
    }
```

Usage could be something like this:

```
    string[] array = SplitRemoveInvalid("Hello! This is a test and it's a short-er 1. - [ ] { } _)")
                     .ToArray();
```

I didnt actually test it, but it should work. If it doesnt, it should be easy enough to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Use [string.Split(char [])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

```
string strings = "4,6,8\n9,4";
string [] split = strings .Split(new Char [] {',' , '\n' });
```

**OR**

Try below if you get any unwanted empty items. [String.Split Method (String[], StringSplitOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx)

```
string [] split = strings .Split(new Char [] {',' , '\n' }, 
                                 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: This does not do what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite easily with a RegEx, by matching words. I am using the following RegEx, which will allow hyphens and apostrophes in the middle of words, but will strip them out if they occur at a word boundary.

```
\w(?:[\w'-]*\w)?
```

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/bC4qX3/2).

In C# it could look like this:

```
private string[] ConvertWordsFromFile(String NewFileText)
{
     return (from m in new Regex(@"\w(?:[\w'-]*\w)?").Matches(NewFileText)
             select m.Value).ToArray();
}
```

I am using LINQ to get an array of words from the `MatchCollection` returned by `Matches`.